# Visual Studio design mode don't work at all ... how can I solve?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ide

Visual Studio ( VS2008 ) design mode work good for long time and from about 2 weeks ago it's suddenly stop view any thing in design mode i tried a lot with trying in another projects even in a simple web page but no way it's doesn't view any thing in design mode ... I think to reinstall VS 2008 again but I don't know if is there any outher solution for that ?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "it doesn't work" if you expect to get meaningful help.

Comment: if you read the the above text you will know what "it doesn't work" mean ? please read carefully before comment

Comment: I did read it. All I got from your post was "It was working before, now it doesn't show anything" which is still extremely non-specific. Do you get a bar at the top of the design viewer showing an internal exception? Do any controls show up in the toolbox? Does the design view respond to mouse interaction? This is all information that is *utterly trivial* for you to find out, but makes it incredibly difficult for anyone else to help if you don't provide it.

Comment: " it's suddenly stop view any thing in design mode" i think from sentence you must understand all what you ask about ?

Comment: At this point, I'm not even sure why I'm bothering. Are you sure you actually want help? No, saying that design mode is blank does not tell me whether or not the toolbox has any controls in it, it does not tell me whether or not design mode is responding to mouse interaction, it does not tell me whether or not VS is notifying you of an internal exception, in fact, it tells me about as much as "it's not working" does. If none of those things are true, then say that! Be specific! It's not hard to type out "The toolbox is empty and the design view doesn't do anything when I click on it".

Comment: i don't know why you are so angry you can ask me what's not clarified to you and i can answer .. it's so easy 
Anyway, no error appear , no exception appear ... Could you help me now or you still have any question ?

Comment: lol, give up Anon. its a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Revert all of your settings to default
2. Try a repair before you do a reinstall.  It's possible that one of the VS assemblies has been overwritten or deregistered by the install of another application

Comment: how can i Revert all of your settings to default ?

Comment: Go to google and search for "how to reset defaults in visual studio"

Comment: You unplug your computer and sit in a dark room for three hours